# Consensus manipulation when using only two peers on a Hyperledger Fabric channel?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

What happens in Hyperledger Fabric on a private channel block-chain consisting of only two peers if one of the peers is faulty and manipulates it's private block chain?

So the two copies of the block chain will diverge and finally it will be impossible for a consensus algorithm to tell which one is correct.

Is this a valid problem? If so, how would this be mitigated? Would it help to add additional peers to the channel (e.g. placed at a regulator's data center) which are not in control of the two peers mentioned above? Or is there a better solution to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding additional peers to each organization would defend against any single node becoming compromised. Adding additional nodes to the channel(s) at an independent 3rd party (auditor, regulator, or other trusted provider) would be another valid strategy to defend against a counter-party with malicious intent.

Comment: If the organization itself is trying to manipulate blocks, adding peers on side would not resolve the issue, am I right with this assumption? This issue would be adressed only if we'd have a node at a 3rd party.
And is it possible, that a peer is part of more than one channel?

Comment: yes, adding peers on one side doesn't help since if the counter-party with malicious intent is in control of the additional peers as well. IMHO one peer can take part of as many channels as desired. In addition, I assume adding peers to just one organization will case an imbalance so that if that organizations becomes malicious it will have an even easier time to compromise the block-chain @christo4ferris can you confirm the last two statements?

Comment: Adding peers to one org will not cause an imbalance, per se.  It would really depend on the endorsement policy for the channel, but it should be possible to defend against this by asserting that you have only 1 of an org's peers sign/validate a transaction.

Answer (score 1):

The consensus is achieved in the Ordering Service, the Peers are independent from it. I think that they are two different things:

1. The Peers don't manipulate the Blockchain. They could send incorrect or invalid transactions. The result of the execution of those transactions depends on the Smart Contrac that you have on the Peers, and the Endorsement Policy that you have defined. Then, each Peer sends the validated transactions to the Ordering Service.
2. The Blocks are created by the Ordering Service, so the blocks will be equal to both peers.

The solution to that issue would be to create an Ordering Service where the **orderers** are located in additional and independent 3rd party.

Nowadys, the Ordering Services gives you the chance to choose among different Services: two different are developed, a third one will be ready soon. More info about it, [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/orderer/README.md#service-types).